# Unable to install conan package eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, conan

I am trying to install some recipes but I am having some kind of authentication issue. when I do

```
conan install eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable
```

I receive the following error

```
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Trying with 'conan-local'...
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Trying with 'bincrafters_remote'...
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Trying with 'conan-community'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt: 100%|##########| 165/165 [00:00<00:00, 345kB/s]
Downloading conanfile.py: 100%|##########| 2.43k/2.43k [00:00<00:00, 7.34MB/s]
Downloading conan_export.tgz: 100%|##########| 766/766 [00:00<00:00, 2.53MB/s]
Decompressing conan_export.tgz: 100%|##########| 766/766 [00:00<00:00, 358kB/s]
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Downloaded recipe revision 0
Installing package: eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable
Requirements
    eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable from 'conan-community' - Downloaded
Packages
    eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Download

eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Retrieving package 5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 from remote 'conan-community'
Downloading conanmanifest.txt: 100%|##########| 42.3k/42.3k [00:00<00:00, 1.22MB/s]
Downloading conaninfo.txt: 100%|##########| 150/150 [00:00<00:00, 460kB/s]
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: ERROR: Exception while getting package: 5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: ERROR: Exception: <class 'conans.errors.ForbiddenException'> Permission denied for user: 'jjcasmar'. [Remote: conan-community]
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: WARN: Trying to remove package folder: /home/jjcasmar/.conan/data/eigen/3.3.7/conan/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9
ERROR: Permission denied for user: 'jjcasmar'. [Remote: conan-community]
```

My remotes are the following:

```
conan-local: some-private-url [Verify SSL: True]
bincrafters_remote: https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan [Verify SSL: True]
conan-community: https://api.bintray.com/conan/conan-community/conan [Verify SSL: True]
conan-center: https://api.bintray.com/conan/conan/conan-center [Verify SSL: True]
```

and the output of `conan user` is the following

```
Current user of remote 'conan-local' set to: 'None' (anonymous)
Current user of remote 'bincrafters_remote' set to: 'None' (anonymous)
Current user of remote 'conan-community' set to: 'jjcasmar' [Authenticated]
Current user of remote 'conan-center' set to: 'None' (anonymous)
```

So, if I am correctly authenticated into conan-community, why am I getting a permission defnied error when trying to install the recipe. Also, I though that for installing recipes there was no need to authenticate so what is happening here?

EDIT:
I have also tried to install the recipe without authentication, but in that case it just asks for a username/password. If I try my bintray username and password, it rejects them.

```
eigen/3.3.7@conan/stable: Retrieving package 5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 from remote 'conan-center' 
Downloading conanmanifest.txt: 100%|##########| 42.3k/42.3k [00:00<00:00, 1.33MB/s]
Downloading conaninfo.txt: 100%|##########| 150/150 [00:00<00:00, 407kB/s]
Please log in to "conan-center" to perform this action. Execute "conan user" command.
If you don't have an account sign up here: https://bintray.com/signup/oss
Remote 'conan-center' username: jjcasmar
Please enter a password for "jjcasmar" account: 
ERROR: Wrong user or password
Remote 'conan-center' username:
```

Comment: Did you try removing the tokens (non-authenticated) and installing? conan user --clean

Comment: Make sure that you are using Conan 1.18.5 at least. There was an authentication error related to urllib3 that affected conan. It can result in download/upload errors.

Comment: I am using conan 1.19.2. I have done user clean --clean and install have the same issue

Comment: Could you please update your error description when unauthenticated? What is the message when you are not logged in?

Comment: I have edited the question as you suggested

Comment: Why are you logged in? Did you run `conan user` to login into conan-center? If not, I can say you are watching a bug

Comment: I didnt the first run. Then I logged, but I have also tried with `conan user -c-clean`, so should be unlogged... I guess it a bug...

Comment: Could you please report your case to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: thank you for reporting it!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue in 2020 on Ubuntu 18.04, and was able to solve it by upgrading to Conan 1.20.2 via the following terminal commands:

`sudo -H pip3 uninstall conan`

`sudo -H pip3 install conan==1.20.2`